# Here's a little cryptogram I wrote, you might want to read it letter for letter

Tags: riddle, cipher, knowledge

Mage's birth seems important.  That's all I'm going to say.

J EJPL QW VFIUQT UXWUTH YOSWSUV, HIU Q JQ PIAX PN HSV.

BQIZ BQMKS R QBG WSU MGMTB,

JRE IV E CQC ASWWK JV CLF PNEE QO M EW.

R EN I KMU JRTPTJV, TWVIUQVIT KQESURRH IWH PBQIS BRQFA FIJZM,

WPUNXJUNW J TROF JNMOO YIFZ PCOB,

BSNMCMNMB M XIWX UW UYSS RR UPN FFVCLJK HSOM

Also, if I completely messed up the encryption, don't get too mad....

Oh, yeah.  And when you've decrypted that, you've got to solve the riddle. :-)

If anyone (who is bothering with the riddle) is having trouble, maybe read below...  It may or may not help.

> Not really that important...  Now I'm getting all science-y on you!

Comment: Any clue as to which fantasy novel is involved this time? :-)

Comment: None, actually... Hahah.  I was looking to do something different that didn't require excessive book knowledge.

Comment: I think I fixed any errors... Dunno.

Comment: Title may refer to [Bobby McFerrin's "Don't Worry, Be Happy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_Worry,_Be_Happy)?

Comment: Anyone think I should post the decrypted text that others have found in a separate post as a riddle?  Or maybe just put it up on this question so non-cyrptographers can solve too. (Is it even allowed?)

Comment: @AJL I'd say just leave it. In practice, most people will look at the existing answers anyway and realise the riddle is all that's left to solve. PS. Is it anything to do with films/TV?

Comment: @rand al'thor  Something to do with media etc., but if one has solved the cipher, you don't need that either.  I did say it has something to do with science.

Comment: @AJL OK, got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to the riddle found by Tryth and TheWamts is

> a QUARK.

*I walk in realms mostly unknown*

> Realms of subatomic particles.

*yet I am part of you.*

> Quarks are what makes up everything, including your body.

*They think I may not exist and am a bit wrong in the heaz.*

> For a long time after the existence of quarks was postulated, many people didn't believe in them.

*If I doz am a bit bipolar,*

> Up and down quarks.

*sometimes charming and other times weird.*

> Charm and strange quarks.

*Sometimes I like being Peer Gynt, sometimes I want to lurk in the Benthic Zone.*

> Truth and beauty quarks maybe? Or a reference to the word Quark being used in a German play *Peer Gynt*, according to [d'alar'cop](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14982/heres-a-little-cryptogram-i-wrote-you-might-want-to-read-it-letter-for-letter/15067?noredirect=1#comment46279_15067).

I got this idea by reading "I am part of you. They think I may not exist" and recalling the following joke:

> "Legally speak­ing, how can you kidnap something that is not supposed to exist? I doubt anyone ever accused Murray Gell-Mann of kidnapping a quark, even though he knowingly carried a billion of them around in his pocket." - Minerva Paradizo, *Artemis Fowl and the Lost Colony*

(quoted from memory - if I got the words slightly wrong, do correct me!) The "sometimes charming and other times weird" was the confirmation I needed for this guess.

Comment: The word "Quark!" is used in a play in German called Peer Gynt. hi rand :D

Comment: @d'alar'cop Thanks - answer updated. http://i.imgur.com/mSagK3N.jpg :-)

Comment: "sleeping".....

Comment: The last clue is incorrect.  Peer gynt refers to a piece of music.  The benthic zone... Well... You can figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

An decoded answer (mostly):

> I walk in real *ms*, mostly unknown yet I am part of you. They think I may not exist and am a bit wrong in the *heaz*. If I *doz* am a bit bipolar, sometimes charming and other times weird. Sometimes I like being Peer Gynt, sometimes I want to lurk in the Benthic Zone. 
> **(decoding errors italicized)**

How it was decoded:

> The cipher appears to be essentially [Vigenere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) with a key of BIJE: This decodes most of it, but has a few errors. Here is the original text after decoding:
> i walk in real ms mostly unknotn yet i am oart of you they thijk i may not exist and am a bit wrong in the heaz if i doz am a bit bipolar sometimes charming and other times weird sometimes i like being peergynt sometimes i want to lurk in the benthicyone
> I have corrected obvious errors but there are a few more I can't easily work out. I suspect what has happened is that the author has invented his own encoding scheme which happens to be equivalent to Vigenere, except it works differently in a few edge cases.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea what Vignere is...  I converted it into a numerical form and then did something with it, for you to find out :-)

Comment: ["peergynt"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_Gynt) doesn't look like a decoding error to me!

Comment: Ahah... Someone noticed.  I thought it might be you.  But a different peergynt.  @rand al'thor How do you add a link?

Comment: @AJL To add a link, write [ link description ]( http :// www. blahblah ) (without the spaces - I just added them so this comment didn't come out as a link!)

Comment: "ms" isn't a decoding error either. Try "I walk in *realms* mostly unknown..." :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I tried a slightly different key as Tryth, and got this:

> Using key 'bijebije':
>  i walk in realms mostly unknotn, yet i am oart of you.they thijk i may not exist,and am a bit wrong in the head if i do.i am a bit bipolar, sometimes charming and other times weird,sometimes i like being peer gynt,sometimes i want to lurk in the benthic yone

Which I translated to:

> i walk in realms mostly unknown, yet i am part of you. they think i may not exist, and am a bit wrong in the head if i do. i am a bit bipolar, sometimes charming and other times weird, sometimes i like being pregnant, sometimes i want to lurk in the ((benthic zone))?

Comment: Umm.. I think they got the peer gynt part right below.  But, pretty good.  Now solve the riddle :-) (free smileys!)

Comment: By peer gynt, are you talking about the musical piece by any chance?

Comment: That's for me to know and for you to find out...(dum dee dum)

Comment: That's actually the same key as Tryth used, because of the way Vigenere works.